# How to get pandas to throw exception (or otherwise note) if some fields are missing from csv?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am reading csv files with pandas in python. When a record in the file has less than the expected number of fields, then pandas just silently fills in the fields with NaN. Instead, I want an exception to be thrown.

For example, if I have a CSV file like this:

```
A, B, C
1, 2, 3
4,,6
5
```

With pandas I can read this file like this:

```
 input_data = pandas.read_csv(input_filename)
```

I want pandas to throw an error on the final line. There should be two more commas on this line (5,,). The missing commas represent missing fields.

Instead of pandas just ignoring the missing commas, is there a way to detect this condition and throw an exception?

Thanks!